# Redirect /500/ to highest existing directory <=500

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Can I somehow redirect all the request to a given directory to any existing directory <= requested directory?
Eg.

/500/ would redirect to 499 because I only have dirs 400-499 and don't have 500

/300/ would redirect to 220 because I only have dirs 200-220 and don't have 300

I mean- treat directory as a number and find highest match that is <= than the requested directory.

Answer (score 2):

mod_rewrite can't do math, and mod_alias (with `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch`) can do less. You can cheat with mod_rewrite using a rewritemap, but that would be fairly inefficient, or the map would need to be remade - and apache needs to restart - everytime you add a new directory. That would be just silly.

I would suggest using a script instead. We use mod_rewrite to test if the directory/file exists, then rewrite to a script if that is not the case.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{3}/ router.php
```

With something like this in router.php

```
<?php
  $num = getNumberFromUrl( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
  while( $num > 0 && !file_exists( "{$num}/" ) {
    $num--;
  }

  if( $num > 0 ) {
    header( "Location: " . replaceNumInUrl( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $num ), 302 );
  }
?>
```

In either case, it probably isn't very efficient.

Comment: Yeah, that’s a fairly easy solution with low complexity. If the directory structure doesn’t change too often, one might consider having them stored in an array that the script can read/include, instead of checking with the file system on each and every request. (Method for manual(?) cache invalidation and re-creating of that data array would have to be implemented then.)

Comment: PHP is an easy solution but quite slow. That's why I am looking for something faster. If I won't I'll use your idea. Thanks!

Comment: The main meat of that slowness comes from testing a lot of directories in your filesystem I would assume. Unless you have a better way of knowing which directories exist, I don't think you'll find anything much faster than this.